# How to print variable inside function

Tags: perl

I'm using [`RRDs::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/RRD::Query) function and it needs bunch of parameters.

I have placed these parameters in a special variable (parsing, sorting and calculating data from a file) with all quotes, commas and other stuff.

Of course

```
RRDs::create ($variable);
```

doesn't work.

I've glanced through all perl special variables and have found nothing.

How to substitute name of variable for the data that contained in that variable?
At least could you tell me with what kind of tools(maybe another special variables) it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding what you're asking:

You've build the 'create' data in $variable, and are now trying to use `RRDs::create` to actually do it?

First step is:

- `print $variable,"\n";` - to see what is actually there. You should be able to use this from the command line, with `rrdtool create`. (Which needs a filename, timestep, and some *valid* `DS` and `RRA` parameters)
- usually, I'll use an array to pass into `RRDs::create`:

  ```
  RRDs::create ( "test.rrd", "-s 300", 
              "DS:name:GAUGE:600:U:U", )
  ```

etc.

If `$variable` contains this information already, then that should be ok. The way to tell what went wrong is:

```
  if ( RRDs::error ) { print RRDs::error,"\n"; }
```

It's possible that creating the file is the problem, or that your RRD definitions are invalid for some reason. `rrdtool create` on command line will tell you, as will `RRDs::error`;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You understand me right. Also thank you for "RRDs::error"! I've found mistake inside $variable. So, turns out I do not need "some special variable", just print errors in RRDs.